# Advanced search expression to find questions with answer(s) when no answer has net upvotes?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions

Without using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, and using only the search bar, is it possible to select just those questions which have:

- one or more answers; and
- no answer on that question has net upvotes?

My understanding is that such questions contribute to the Unanswered count for a site, and are ripe for review to see whether any of their answers warrant an upvote to remove them from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query `answers:1 closed:0 isanswered:0 hasaccepted:0` comes close to what you want: it finds all questions which

- have at least 1 answer
- are not closed (closed questions are not considered unanswered)
- have no answer with positive score
- have no accepted answer.

The four parts of the query are responsible for the four properties above, in the same order.

It's possible that the answers all have the score of -1 or less, in which case upvoting won't remove the post from Unanswered; but this is relatively uncommon.